# Gradle and src/main/resources

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a gradle project which is working fine within eclipse.  In the java code I have

```
Properties p = MyClass.class.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("myProps.properties");

File f = new File(p.getProperty("myFile"));
```

My structure is:

```
src/main/java - has java files
src/main/resources - has myProps.properties and myFile.txt
```

myProps.properties has:

```
myFile=src/main/resources/myFile.txt
```

If I do a gradle build (using a default shadowJar task) my resources have now been moved from src/main/resources to the root of the jar file.

```
shadowJar {
   manifest{
     // The only thing I modify is the attributes
   }
}
```

When I execute the jar by running
"java -jar myJar.jar" I get FileNotFound exception referring to the myFile.txt resource file.

What is the correct way to fix this issue so that the code works from both  the Eclipse and executable jar environments?

Comment: You can't open myFile.txt as a File when it's just an entry in a jar file. You have to open it as a resource instead, using getResourceAsStream.

Comment: Yep, just figured that out. You're right :)  I now read it as a stream and its good to go

Answer (score 1):

I needed to read the file as a stream (the same way I read in the properties file). I removed 'src/main/resources' from the path in the properties file and it worked